# Testing Varying Parameters With the Same Script

Tags: c++

As the title suggests, I would like to test different values of parameters with the same code in C++.

For example, one of the parameters is: `#define α 0.5`. I would like to run the same code, but with different values of `α`, like `#define α 0.6`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this belongs in this forum, but I am assunming these are some parameters of an optimisation function or something similar.

Preprocessor directives are an unfavourable way of defining parameters in your case, I would say. Why? Because C++ takes all the instances of `α` in your *code* and replaces them with `0.5`. Note, the replacement is done in the code, and not the memory.

Now, you would like to run an additional layer of replacements on top of this (that changes the values of the macro in every execution), which according to me is not an option.

**Solution**: Instead of using macros, declare your parameter as a global variable. Take the value of this parameter as a command line argument. See [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/) tutorial.

Then, write a bash script (maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59768931/bash-script-to-compile-and-run-c-program) question helps) that builds and runs your code with the commmand line argument in a loop (or however you like), but changes the command line argument in each execution. See [this](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial) tutorial for help with bash scripting.